# 'list' object has no attribute 'method'

Tags: python

I have a list with measurements, like:

```
[[Measurements(100, 0.3)],
[Measurements(33, 0.5)]]
```

Then , I have a list with some criteria which contains list of measurements:

```
 [Criteria(999, [[Measurements(100, 0.3)],
                        [Measurements(33, 0.5)]])],

 [Criteria(999, [[Measurements(150, 0.3)],
                        [Measurements(35, 0.5)]])]
```

Finally, I want to supply the above list as input and execute the code:

```
class Measurements():
    def __init__(self, value, other):
        self.value = value
        self.other = other


class Criteria():
    def __init__(self, new_value, measurements):
        self.new_value = new_value
        self.measurements = measurements

    def method(self):

        # Here, I am iterating through all measurements
        # and replace the value according to criteria
        for idx, x in enumerate(self.measurements):
            if (self.measurements[idx].value > 20 and
                    self.measurements[idx].value < 110):

                self.measurements[idx].value = self.new_value
        return self.measurements


class Evaluate():
    def __init__(self, criteria):
        self.criteria = criteria

    def execute(self):
        criteria = self.criteria

        # Here, I am iterating through all criteria
        # and call the method from criteria
        for i, c in enumerate(criteria):
            c.method()
            return c.measurements


def main():

    criteria = [
        [Criteria(999, [[Measurements(100, 0.3)],
                        [Measurements(33, 0.5)]])],

        [Criteria(999, [[Measurements(150, 0.3)],
                        [Measurements(35, 0.5)]])]
    ]

    obs = (Evaluate(criteria).execute())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

and I am receiving `c.method()
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'method'`

I want my results to be the new corrected Measurements, so :

```
[[Measurements(999, 0.3)],
[Measurements(999, 0.5)]],
[Measurements(150, 0.3)],
[Measurements(999, 0.5)]]
```

Comment: Why do you have nested lists? `c` is `[Criteria(999, ...)]`, a list with one element in it, *not* `Criteria(999, ...)`.

Comment: I have nested lists because I will have many criteria that I want to evaluate.

Comment: That doesn't require *nested* lists..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All your `Criteria()` and `Measurement()` objects each are stored in a *one-element list*, which in turn are stored in a larger list. Either account for this, or don't use one-element nested lists.

I don't see any reason for those one-element lists; the following definition should make your code work:

```
criteria = [
    Criteria(999, [Measurements(100, 0.3), Measurements(33, 0.5)]),
    Criteria(999, [Measurements(150, 0.3), Measurements(35, 0.5)]),
]
```

You'll otherwise will have to either extract that one element each time, or use nested loops:

```
def execute(self):
    for c in self.criteria:
        c[0].method()
```

or

```
def execute(self):
    for c_list in self.criteria:
        for c in c_list:
            c.method()
```

You should also *not* use `return` in a `for` loop, at least not if you want to get the measurements for *all* criteria. Collect the measurements in a list, then return that list.

You also are using `self` way too many times in the `Criteria.method()` loop. There is no need for `enumerate()`, you don't need indices to alter mutable objects.

Corrected code:

```
class Measurements():
    def __init__(self, value, other):
        self.value = value
        self.other = other


class Criteria():
    def __init__(self, new_value, measurements):
        self.new_value = new_value
        self.measurements = measurements

    def method(self):
        for measurement in self.measurements:
            if 20 < measurement.value < 110:
                measurement.value = self.new_value
        return self.measurements

class Evaluate():
    def __init__(self, criteria):
        self.criteria = criteria

    def execute(self):
        results = []
        for c in self.criteria:
            measurements = c.method()
            results.extend(measurements)
        return results

def main():
    criteria = [
        Criteria(999, [Measurements(100, 0.3), Measurements(33, 0.5)]),
        Criteria(999, [Measurements(150, 0.3), Measurements(35, 0.5)]),
    ]

    obs = Evaluate(criteria).execute()
```

Comment: Ok,thanks for the help and suggestions!So,my main problem was the nested lists and it didn't work at all!Regarding the return , in the for loop it will return only the first calculations, right?(upvoted)

Comment: @George: exactly; `return` will exit the function right there, so only the first result would be returned.

Comment: Thank you.Can you tell me in [that case](http://pastebin.com/Dc7dzaVp) how can I deal with the return if I have many cases? (I mean,ok I can have many for loops in every case,but I was wondering if there is something else)

Comment: In my answer I simply gather the results into a list, then *after* the loop use `return`. Sure, you can use `yield` to produce a generator, but that's a more advanced technique mostly used to save memory (you don't have to hold a whole list in memory if you only are interested in processing elements in isolation). Since you are working with objects already loaded in memory here, that's not really necessary.

Comment: In your last example, you removed all benefits of `yield` by calling `list` on it anyway. And you never use the indices produced by `enumerate()`; don't use `enumerate()` if you are not actually needing the extra information it generates.

Comment: So, in my  last example (using yield), how can I extract the values?

Comment: And the problem is that if I don't use yield, I have to use many for loops for every case ( because i have various if statements) with many returns

Comment: Sounds like you might want to ask a new question then; comments are not really the place for follow-up problems.

Comment: I was writting [one!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42110061/using-yield-print-output)