# using yield print output

Tags: python, yield

This is a continuation from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42101084/list-object-has-no-attribute-method).

I am using `yield` statement instead of `return`.

This is the code:

```
class Measurements():
    def __init__(self, value, other):
        self.value = value
        self.other = other


class Criteria():
    def __init__(self, new_value, measurements):
        self.new_value = new_value
        self.measurements = measurements

    def method(self):
        for measurement in self.measurements:
            if 20 < measurement.value < 110:
                measurement.value = self.new_value
        return self.measurements

class Evaluate():
    def __init__(self, criteria):
        self.criteria = criteria

    def execute(self):
        for c in self.criteria:
            c.method()
            yield c.measurements


def main():
    criteria = [
        Criteria(999, [Measurements(100, 0.3), Measurements(33, 0.5)]),
        Criteria(999, [Measurements(150, 0.3), Measurements(35, 0.5)]),
    ]

    compare =  [
        Measurements(999, 0.3), Measurements(999, 0.5),
        Measurements(100, 0.3), Measurements(999, 0.5)
    ]

    obs = Evaluate(criteria).execute()

    # here compare

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I want to compare my output values from `obs` with the values in the `compare`. I am refering to the `Measurements` part.

So, from `obs`, we have (for the variable value after running the code) :`999,999,150,999`  ( because if 20

and from `compare` we have: `999,999,100,999`

Comment: Continuation from what? What is the actual question or problem?

Comment: @ChristophTerasa:I edited,but it is standalone anyway.

Comment: How are you wanting to compare them? `obs` is a generator so you can iterate through the values.

Comment: "I want to compare my output values from obs with the values in the compare". Please explain why `list(obs) == compare` does not meet your needs.

Comment: @scytale: Yes, I tried using for loop with enumerate but I couldn't figure

Comment: @scytale: Hmm.nice but : 1) I may want to compare only the `value` part of `Measurements` 2) I am not sure how to use it properly, If I do `assert list(obs) == compare`  it throws `assertionerror`

Comment: Well yes, you get the `AssertionError` because your lists aren't exactly the same. So do you want to check if all values are the same or find which values at the same index match? Or if compare contains any values from obs?

Comment: @StevenSummers:One case is check if all values are same ( so the whole `Measurements` is ok,hence `value` and `other` are the same ).Other case is check only the `value` from the obs (which is the result) with the `value` from the compare.(assertion doesn't work either if I simply use print)

Comment: Why are you using classes instead of simply stuffing your data into `numpy` arrays? I do not know if your problem will get more involved down the line, but this looks like overkill and a lot of complications for a simple problem.

Comment: @ChristophTerasa:Because every part does a specific job.Criteria is applying the various criteria to the various input data.Then, the result is being evaluated and it must be returned to an array for example.And then evaluate tihs array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Still a bit unsure on what checks you wanted to perform, but here is an example that should get you started. Couple of changes were made

```
# Made compare a list contain lists of Measurements to match criteria
compare =  [
    [Measurements(999, 0.3), Measurements(999, 0.5)],
    [Measurements(100, 0.3), Measurements(999, 0.5)]
]
```

---

```
# Added __repr__ method to Measurement class
def __repr__(self):
    return '{0} {1}'.format(self.value, self.other)
```

I suggest doing this whenever you have a list of class instances, it makes debugging much easier as instead of getting this, you get something more meaningful.

```
<__main__.Measurements object at 0x0000000003E2C438>
```

---

Now for comparing the values I used `zip` to group the two lists together making it easier to compare the values. Then for the inner for loop we again zip the nested lists from each group together. From here each item is a Measurement that we can check their values of.

```
for crit_lst, comp_lst in zip(obs, compare):
    for crit_meas, comp_meas in zip(crit_lst, comp_lst):
        print(crit_meas, comp_meas)
        if crit_meas.value != comp_meas.value: # example of comparing their values
            print('Mis-Match', crit_meas.value, comp_meas.value)
```

Comment: Thanks!That was exactly what I was looking for.(upvoted)

Answer (score 1):

I do not know if you really need the two-dimensional structure of your Measurements, this turns this into a three-dimensional structure in numpy. If that is not necessary you can drop the extra dimension.

```
import numpy as np

lower = 20
upper = 110

meas = np.array([[[100, 0.3], [33, 0.5]], [[150, 0.3], [35, 0.5]]])
crit = np.array([[999, 999]])
comp = np.array([[[100, 0.3], [33, 0.5]], [[150, 0.3], [35, 0.5]]])

mask = (meas[:,:,0] > lower) * (meas[:,:,0] < upper)

meas[mask,0] = (mask * crit)[mask] # apply mask to inner first column

out = (meas == comp).all(axis=2) # compare each measurement to respective one in comp

print(out)
```

This gives:

```
[[False False]
 [ True False]]
```

Comment: Thanks,nice solution,but notwhat I was looking for right now(upvoted)